# All my grails static resources from my plugin get /static/ added to them automatically. I don't want that

Tags: grails-plugin

Grails M2 version

In my plugin views I reference images from my plugin in my gsp's like

```
${resource(dir: '/images/checklist', file: 'subscribe.png', plugin:'mypluginname')}
```

The directory `/images/checklist` is in the web-apps directory.

When I run this, the filename used for the resource is

```
/static/plugins/mypluginname-0.1/images/checklist/subscribe.png
```

So where is the `/static/` coming from?  It doesn't find the image.  If I ping the web server without the `/static` it works fine.

I don't think the static should be there.  Am I right?

I also tried it with a relative path for the directory as

```
${resource(dir: 'images/checklist', file: 'subscribe.png', plugin:'mypluginname')}
```

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Can fix this in Config.groovy by setting: grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = []

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Resources plugin serves the modified static resources from URIs beginning with /static/.

You can change this by assigning a value to grails.resources.uri.prefix

**Config.groovy**

```
grails.resources.uri.prefix = ''
```

Reference:
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html